# Datatable loading icon in modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

Is it possible while loading/searching/sorting jquery datatables to display the loading icon in a bootstrap Modal? 
is there any example

Comment: Why you want to show a loading image in a Modal ? It's good to show it on the page itself Right ?

Comment: Because i'm loading some heavy data and sometimes it take a while and i would like to prevent the user from navigating away.
also the standard loading icon is displayed in the middle of the table and if user decided to show 100+ records, the loading icon will be hidden because user will need to scroll in order to display it

Comment: No. You can keep the loading image in center of the page, no matter how many records you fetch. It's just a css. Anyway, I'm writing an answer plz check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Bootstrap modal in your view, for example,

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Loading...</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Please wait. It's loading data.</p>
      <img src="my loading gif url here" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your Search datatable,

```
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {  //This is an example
 //here load the Modal
 $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
 //Here call your Ajax method to call your Action Method or Api blah blah
 //Then in success method of your Ajax, hide the Modal, like,
 success:function(result)
 {
  //Your rest code here
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
 } 
} );
```

Same like you can call the Modal in pagination etc etc.

**Note:** See I set `data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"` in Bootstrap Modal, so that user can't able to close that since the data fetching and loading. It will automatically hide.

**Updated:**
As you have commented bellow, you have no Ajax success method. So there is a properties of Datatable called **fnInitComplete** where you can hide your Modal. For example,

```
"fnInitComplete": function () 
 {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
 }
```

That's it.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks basanta, but should i give the standard search box of datatable an id? i see you call it myInput
also for me it's important the modal to be displayed when loading the datatable and hid when done
do you know what events should i use because i tested them one by one with no success

Comment: That's why I mentioned next to that line **This is an example**. No matter how you are calling your Action Method or Api to fetch data, before that you can call the Bootstrap Modal and hide that in success.

Comment: There is a properties of datatable called **fnInitComplete** . Here you can hide the Modal popup. For example, `"fnInitComplete": function () { $('#myModal').modal('hide');}`

Comment: I used the following event beforeSend to start and complete to end
but every time i type one letter in the search it starts the loading
my datatables using server side processing with many data so it takes seconds for each search

Comment: PS: fnInitComplete doesn't fires when sorting and paging so the modal will keep open